# swift でエラーが出る: [<o2.ViewController 0x7fa9f0706c90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key b

Tags: swift

４つのtext filedに値を入れ計算した３つ答えを書き出すアプリを開発しています。
iPhoneのデモ画面を起動したところ以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。
作成したコードにはエラー表示がされていませんでした。

以下のサイトを参考にエラーをなくそうとしたのですが...
どのようにすればエラーが解決するでしょうか？ご教授お願いいたします。

[swift初心者:「this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key」の対処方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Atsushi_/items/f7930dd00a2c2ea464cd)

```swift
    2021-05-15 17:34:29.504344+0900 o2[3184:117685] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<o2.ViewController 0x7fa9f0706c90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key b.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422fba __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20193ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422c5b -[NSException init] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff207af46c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 331
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f7cac4 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 74
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff242bbc0b -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2040c6e6 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 228
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff242b7e70 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2175
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f84921 -[UIViewController loadView] + 668
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f84cbc -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23f85436 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246ffc73 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 313
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246ff362 -[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:actionBlock:] + 219
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24700325 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 362
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff247133a6 -[UIWindow _mainQueue_makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24951c05 -[UIWindowScene _makeKeyAndVisibleIfNeeded] + 202
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23b0e80c +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1671
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c2df9 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 1114
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c3128 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 289
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff241a4ab4 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 358
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25a1b40b -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 398
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25a43e55 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.176 + 102
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25a28f12 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 209
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25a43b28 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 352
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101e9174e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101e94656 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 295
    26  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25a695d0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25a692b6 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 433
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff25a6977b -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20390ede __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20390dd6 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 180
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20390300 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038a9f7 __CFRunLoopRun + 875
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038a1a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2b874d85 GSEventRunModal + 139
    35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c14df -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c639c UIApplicationMain + 101
    37  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff53fcbf42 $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 98
    38  o2                                  0x0000000101c0a42a $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 122
    39  o2                                  0x0000000101c0a39e $s2o211AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 46
    40  o2                                  0x0000000101c0a4c9 main + 41
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff2025abbd start + 1
    42  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<o2.ViewController 0x7fa9f0706c90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key b.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 757.5 - Device: iPhone 8 (471D3BE9-5C7E-49C1-970B-3C3BF7226727) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) - DeviceType: iPhone 8
```

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var L: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var M_MPa: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var L_MPa: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var l_m: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var gus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var last_m: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var last_L: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        L.placeholder = "内積量(L)を入力してください"
        M_MPa.placeholder = "maxの充填圧力(MPa)を入力してください"
        L_MPa.placeholder = "残り充填圧力(MPa)を入力してください"
        l_m.placeholder = "患者使用流(L/分)を入力してください"
    }
    @IBAction func calcurate(_ sender: Any) {
        let double_g = Double(L_MPa.text!)
        let double_c = Double(l_m.text!)
        let double_a = Double(L.text!)
        let double_b = Double(M_MPa.text!)
        gus.text = calculation1(L_MPa:double_g!, l_m:double_c!,L: double_a!, M_MPa:double_b!)
        
        last_m.text = calculation2(L_MPa:double_g!, l_m:double_c!,L: double_a!, M_MPa:double_b!)
        
        last_L.text = calculation3(L_MPa:double_g!, l_m:double_c!,L: double_a!, M_MPa:double_b!)
    }
    
    func calculation1(L_MPa:Double, l_m:Double,L:Double, M_MPa:Double)-> String{
        let a = L
        let b = M_MPa
        var d = (a*b*10.0)//varはletではできない書き換えができる
        d = (a*b*10.0)
        return d.description
    }
    func calculation2(L_MPa:Double, l_m:Double,L:Double, M_MPa:Double)-> String{
        let c = l_m
        let a = L
        let b = M_MPa
        let d = (a*b*10.0)
        var e = (d/c)
        e = (d/c)
        return e.description
    }
    func calculation3(L_MPa:Double, l_m:Double,L:Double, M_MPa:Double)-> String{
        let g = L_MPa
        let a = L
        let b = M_MPa
        var d = (a*b*10.0)
        d = (a*b*10.0)
        var f = d*(g/b)
        f = d*(g/b)
        return f.description
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 作成したコードにはエラー表示がされていませんでした。

ビルド時のエラー(プログラミング言語の構文上のエラーなど、そもそも実行することができない、と言うエラー)と実行時のエラーは区別できるようにしてください。「コードにはエラー表示がされていません」と言う状態で実行時エラーが発生することはいくらでも考えられます。

> 以下のサイトを参考にエラーをなくそうとしたのですが...

具体的に何をどうしたのかを書いてください。リンク先の記事は、細かいところで正確とは程遠いですが、

- Connection inspectorを開く
- ×を押して不要な接続を削除する

と言う対処方法は変わりません。(何が「不要な接続」かわからないのであれば、すべての接続を削除してください。)

---

なお、デバッグコンソールなどに具体的なエラーメッセージが出ている場合のご質問には、そのエラーメッセージをご質問のタイトルに(長ければ要約して)含められた方がいいでしょう。

> `[<o2.ViewController 0x7fa9f0706c90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key b.`

このエラーは、iOSがstoryboardの設定に従って`@IBOutlet`を接続しようとしているときに、「`ViewController`には、`b`なんて名前のIBOutletが無い!」と言う場合に発生するものです。

Connection inspectorを開いたときに何かのUI要素(おそらく`UITextField`)の接続先が`ViewController`の **`b`** になっているところはありませんか? 見つかれば、それを削除、見つからなければ、全部削除して全部つなぎ直しましょう。

また、Xcodeは時折不安定な動作になることがあり、Connection inspector上で接続を削除しても同じ実行時エラーが出続けることがあります。そのような場合には、storyboard内の設定を一旦全部捨てて、部品の配置とIBAction/IBOutletの接続をやり直さないといけないかもしれません。

---

まずは上記の(記事内の)対処方法をきちんとやって見てください。それでもうまくいかない場合には、なにをどうやってどうなっていたのか、と言うことをできるだけ詳しく記録して、ご質問の本文に追記してください。